# SWIFT 3 - filtering dictionary values with myUserSelectedArray

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an app that will be used to identify potential illnesses based on symptoms? There is a list of symptoms that the app user chooses from by placing a check next to each symptom they are experiencing.

myDictionary will represent twenty different illnesses (keys) with associated symptoms (values)

myUserSelectedArray will be the symptoms that the user selects.

The list of symptoms presented to the user to choose from are the combination of all of the symptoms (values) from the various illnesses (keys) from myDictionary

The app will show the user the top 5 illnesses that they may potentially have based on their symptoms and it will display the percentage of the symptoms matched to each illness. For example, the app might display to the user the following: 1) Flu: 50% symptom match; 2) Sinus Infection: 40% symptom match; 3) Strep Throat: 20% symptom match; 4) Ear Infection: 10% symptom match; 5) Throat Cancer: 5% symptom match

How would I proper filter myDictionary with myUserSelectedArray in order to achieve these results?

Any code suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am new to app development but I have a ton of different ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting an additional dictionary for listing all of the symptoms for a given illness and reversing `myDictionary`. So you'd have three data structures in total: `illnessesToSymptoms`, `symptomsToIllnesses`, `userSymptoms`.

For example:

```
let illnessesToSymptoms = [
    "flu" : ["fever", "runny nose", "chills"],
    "strep throat" : ["fever", "aches", "sore throat"],
    "ear infection" : ["ear pain"]
]

let symptomsToIllnesses = [
    "fever" : ["flu", "strep throat"],
    "runny nose" : ["flu"],
    "aches" : ["strep throat"],
    "ear pain" : ["ear infection"]
]

let userSymptoms = ["fever", "runny nose"]
```

This way you can generate a new dictionary with information that can be used to calculate those probabilities.

```
var possibleIllnesses = [String : Int]()

for userSymp in userSymptoms {
    guard let ills = symptomsToIllnesses[userSymp] else { continue }
    for ill in ills {
        guard let _ = possibleIllnesses[ill] else {
            possibleIllnesses[ill] = 1
            continue
        }
        possibleIllnesses[ill]! += 1
    }
}
```

And from there it's easy to find the chances.

```
for (illness, count) in possibleIllnesses {
    let chance = Double(count) / Double(illnessesToSymptoms[illness]!.count) * 100
    print("There is a \(chance)% they have \(illness)")
}
```

For the example above, this prints:

```
There is a 33.3333333333333% they have strep throat
There is a 66.6666666666667% they have flu
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the help. Do you recommend any learning programs that you have done that helped you learn Swift and/or Android code for mobile apps?

Comment: @salanthonyc There are some specific guides out there, but I'd recommend trying to jump in on your own. Try to tackle some small apps that'd you like to use. You'll run into challenges along the way, but I think it's the best way to learn.